# Multi-file arduino esp8266 sketch sharing a reference to server

Tags: arduino, esp8266

As my sketches get bigger, the code looks awful as one file and the number of global variables is too high.

For the webconfig part of my sketch the device attempts to get online and if it fails it scans for available wifi networks, goes into Access Point Mode, starts a server, sends the list of ssid's and listens for a response of an ssid/passwd pair. The server is only for the configuration.

Ideally I'd like the cleaned up main.ino file to look like

```
#include "config.h"
void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("--------------------------");
  Serial.println("ESP8266 multifile");
  Serial.println("--------------------------");
  getOnline();
}
void loop(){
    if(IN_CONFIG_MODE){
       server.handleClient();
    }
}
```

with a config.h something like..

```
    #ifndef config_h
    #define config_h
        #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
        #include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
        ESP8266WebServer server;
        void getOnline();
    #endif
```

and then a config.cpp where it does all stuff described above yet gives the main.ino program access to the `server` instance so it can listen in the main loop.

```
#include "config.h"
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

char *espssid = "espAPsb";
char *ssid = "street_no_vale2";
char *pwd = "jjjjjjjjx";
char ssids[300];

extern server(80);

void handleRoot(){
    server.send(200, "text/html", "<h1>root of espAPsb AP server</h1>");
    //send json of available ssids
}

void scan(){
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.disconnect();
  delay(100);
  int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
  Serial.println("scan done");  
  if (n == 0)
    Serial.println("no networks found");
  else
  {
    Serial.print(n);
    Serial.println(" networks found");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
      // Print SSID and RSSI for each network found
      Serial.print(i + 1);
      Serial.print(": ");
      Serial.print(WiFi.SSID(i));
      Serial.print(" (");
      Serial.print(WiFi.RSSI(i));
      Serial.print(")");
      Serial.println((WiFi.encryptionType(i) == ENC_TYPE_NONE)?" ":"*");
      delay(10);
    }
  }
  Serial.println("");   
}

void setupAP(){
    WiFi.softAP(espssid);
    server.on("/", handleRoot);
    server.begin();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("connected as AP ");
  Serial.println(espssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.softAPIP());  
}

void getOnline(){
    WiFi.begin(ssid, pwd);
  int tries =0;
  int success=1;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED ) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
    tries++;
    if (tries==15){
      success=0;
      Serial.println("WiFi not connected");
      scan();
      setupAP();
      break;
    }
  }
  if (success){
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi connected");
    Serial.print("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());    
  } 
}
```

Comment: This is no C code. Arduino is not C or (standard) C++.

Comment: True, but my problem is with the 'c-like' parts, header files, declarations extern variables and classes that I see in many of the libraries that support these microcontrollers. It's more like C than it is like javascript:)

Comment: There are more programming languages than C and JavaScript. C does not have classes. Please do some research. Processing is based on C++ (but not exactly like C++).

Comment: Wow the world is changing. These days Github issues is so where it is at. `extern ESP8266WebServer server;` goes in the .h file and  `ESP8266WebServer server(80)` goes in the .cpp file. It would be like that in c++ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an own library from your networking code, which you can easily reuse.
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/LibraryTutorial

Alternatively, you can use multiple "tabs" in Arduino IDE which works like a standard multi-source project. http://arduino.land/FAQ/content/7/43/en/breaking-a-sketch-into-multiple-files.html

(Btw, StackExchange hosts a dedicated Ardunio microsite here: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ Have fun there :)

Comment: copied to arduino.stackechange on the advice of @Gee_Bee I can get https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/LibraryTutorial to work as well as http://arduino.land/FAQ/content/7/43/en/breaking-a-sketch-into-multiple-files.html and http://arduinoetcetera.blogspot.com/2011/01/classes-within-classes-initialiser.html I can even get extern references to variables to work but referencing the an instance of ESP8266WebServer in different files is still beyond me

Comment: Oh, so then your question is "how to refer to a variable declared in another source file" instead of "how to better structure my code in multiple source files/libraries". Roger that. You declare the variable (i.e. the ESP8266WebServer instance) in one file, and you can refer that by the extern keyword in another file, see http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=43507.0

Comment: *However* if you wanna have it nice, I'd make an own cpp class with the ESP8266 specific code, and would use that from my Arduino sketch. For example, your new cpp class could have one connect() method (aka getOnline) which you can nicely call from your main sketch. This is much better approach than letting the ESP8266WebServer instance being referred in all other souce codes - that would really break the concept of modular programming.

Comment: Yeah that's where I was heading. My problem was I still needed to use server,handleClient() in the main loop so I needed a reference to server. I suppose I could wrap that too inside a Config class and then just call cfg.getOnline() in setup and cfg.handleConfig() in loop.

Comment: Exactly. Once you go further with programming, you will get more strict advices on this, telling that never leak your references ;-) For "reference" (no pun intended), check e.g. how Serial is made. It has one begin method what you call in the setup - and then it has methods what you call in loop. Same thing shall work here :)